# Как использовать именованные группы (regex) в sublime text?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, boost, sublime-text

Пробовал по этой [документации](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) таким образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в результате происходила просто замена на строку `k<NAME>`.

Comment: Я бы предположил что как обычно используется ```$<Name>``` но не могу утверждать

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был найден [здесь](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/perl_format.html):

Так создаётся именованная группа:

```
(?<NAME>expression)
```

Так она выбирается:

```
$+{NAME}
```